# LAPACK array size and returns

Tags: c++, lapack

I am using lapack dggglm to solves a general Gauss-Markov linear model (GLM) problem in C++. I designed a loop which does something like:

```
B=zeros(N);P=zeros(N);L=zeros(N); X=zeros(N); Y=zeros(N); //allocating memory
for(i=0;i<100;i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<M;j++) //M<=N
   { 
       B[j]=something; //do simimar things for P, L, X, Y 
   }
   dggglm_(&row, &col, &row, B, &row, P, &row, L, X, Y, work, &lwork, &info);
}
```

My question is that for each iteration, I have a different size of matrix (B,P,L,X,Y). So, using B as an example, can I just define a large enough matrix B before the for loop and update its values on each iteration? Can I assume the LAPACK only reads B(1 to row*col) althoug B is actually longer than that?

Another question is that the document said (Y is destroyed on exit). What's the meaning of this, do I need to reallocate memory for Y at each iteration?

Comment: Yes you can assume that. Where does it say Y is destroyed on exit?

Comment: Thanks, ChrisD. That's my mistake. It is L, not Y, that being destroyed. See here http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dc/dd2/group__double_o_t_h_e_reigen_gaa7c4f7b52f415b808e935845f19300ed.html. I found on another website that to destroy means to overwrite (https://www.nag.com/numeric/fl/nagdoc_fl25/html/f08/f08zbf.html).